# How to use FB login with multiple app ids in one page?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I wanted to give 2 Facebook login buttons(different apps) in a single html page.

As I investigated there is no direct way to do it. I tried to call init method onclick of login button but it didn't help.

Below is the JS SDK code.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'your-app-id',
        autoLogAppEvents: true,
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v3.2'
    });
};

(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
    }
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Is there any alternative way to do this?

Comment: iframes may be a solution. but i would just avoid multiple apps per page.

Comment: There is no way to have the JS SDK run with two different app ids in the same page. If you only need this for login, you could maybe try and initialize it only after one of your two login buttons has been clicked (need to use your own buttons and call FB.login then) - but that’s likely to lead to issues with the popup blocker. Switching to the server-side login flow might be another alternative.